# ExpoGo SocketTimeOutException - Android Studio and mobile device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a lot of trouble opening my expo project, I simply can't open the project in any device. If I try to connect (I already tried LAN and tunnel) it doesn't work. Like, never. The project is running on WSL1, which my backend is also running, but I can access my backend endpoints with no problem with other devices in the same network.

I already deactivated firewalls, changed my network to private and literally every other answer that was directed to this question before, I literally don't know what to do anymore. It seems like an Expo problem, but idk.